# Show that for every family of sets $\{A_i ⊆ X : i ∈ I\}$ we have $\overline{\bigcup_{i∈I} A_i} ⊇ \bigcup_{i∈I} \overline{A}_i$.

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Show that for every family of sets $\{A_i ⊆ X : i ∈ I\}$ (where $I$ can be either finite or infinite), we have $\overline{\bigcup_{i∈I} A_i} ⊇ \bigcup_{i∈I} \overline{A}_i$.

Provide an example in which the inclusion is strict.

My attempt:

$A_i ⊆ \bigcup_{i \in I}A_i$, then $\overline{A}_i ⊆ \overline{ \bigcup_{i \in I} A_i}$. This implies that $\bigcup_{i \in I} \overline{A}_i ⊆ \overline{\bigcup_{i \in I} A_i}$. Is it correct?

And what is an example in which the inclusion is strict?

Comment: Proper MathJax usage is $\bigcup_{i\in I} A_i, $ not $U_{i\in I} A_i.$ Things like this can be found by google "latex symbols." I did that and some other corrections of notation.

Comment: Also $\{\text{curly braces}\}$ should be inside the MathJax code, not outside. Thus: $$ \{A_i \subseteq X : i \in I\} $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct.

One example is $A_n=1/n,~n\in\mathbb{N}$

$\overline{\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}A_n} = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\overline{A_n}\cup\{0\}$, where $\overline{A_n}=A_n$